# Get Radio Button Value Android

Tags: android, forms, android-intent, radio-button

I am trying to make a simple form activity in order to learn how to use the various components supplied by Eclipse. I was doing great until I got to the radio buttons.

The application allows a user to fill out an entire form and then click the send button. When the send button is clicked I create a new intent, pass all of the form data into the intent and start up a new activity to act as a sort of confirmation/summary page.

How do I go about retrieving which radiobutton the user has clicked? I have five in total. 
Below is the code from my onCreate method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.feedback_scroll);

    //References to XML
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameEntryBox);
    county = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.countySpinner);

    //Set array adapter
    county.setAdapter(fillCountySpinner());
    submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitFormBtn);

    atmo1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.arad1);
    atmo2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.arad2);
    atmo3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.arad3);
    atmo4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.arad4);
    atmo5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.arad5);

    ser1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.srad1);
    ser2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.srad2);
    ser3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.srad3);
    ser4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.srad4);
    ser5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.srad5);

    rating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);

    //Add a listener to the submit button - Anonymous inner class
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create a new Intent
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), FeedbackResults.class);

            choice = (String)county.getSelectedItem();
            //Add extra parameters

            //Name
            i.putExtra("name", name.getText());
            //County
            i.putExtra("county", choice);
            //Dob
            //Atmosphere
            i.putExtra("atmosphere", atmos);
            //Service
            i.putExtra("service", serv);
            //Rating
            i.putExtra("rating", rating.getRating());

            //Start new Activity that will display a review of the customers feedback
            startActivity(i);

            //Toast message
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Thank you for your feedback!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

I was looking at another topic relating to my question on this site. They said to use a switch statement. I understand the logic with it and wrote in the methods to do this, but I don't know how to pass the View variable to it..What is this view variable relating to?? THis is the method I wrote.

```
    public void onRadioButtonClicked1(View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.arad1:
        atmos = "1";
        break;
    case R.id.arad2:
        atmos = "2";
        break;
    case R.id.arad3:
        atmos = "3";
         break;
    case R.id.arad4:
        atmos = "4";
        break;
    case R.id.arad5:
        atmos = "5";
        break;
    }

}
```

Any feedback is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each group of radio buttons should be in a group, I assume you did this already in your XML file.

Assuming that, then you get the ID of the checked radio button by doing:

```
int id = ((RadioGroup)findViewById( R.id.radio_group )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

You can do that anywhere in an `Activity`, or if you're using a `Fragment`, then you just need to put a `getView()` in it:

```
int id = ((RadioGroup)getView().findViewById( R.id.radio_group )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

So I would change your `onClick`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Create a new Intent
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), FeedbackResults.class);

    choice = (String)county.getSelectedItem();
    int id = ((RadioGroup)findViewById( R.id.radio_group )).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    atmos = getAtmos( id );
    ...
}

private int getAtmos( int id ) {
    switch( id ) {
        case R.id.arad1:
            atmos = "1";
            break;
        case R.id.arad2:
            atmos = "2";
            break;
        case R.id.arad3:
            atmos = "3";
             break;
        case R.id.arad4:
            atmos = "4";
        break;
        case R.id.arad5:
            atmos = "5";
            break;
    }

    return atmos;
}
```

Comment: I actually did not put my radio buttons in a group at all! But It makes plenty of sense to do so! I will try what you suggested now.