# How to get radiobutton value?

Tags: java, gwt

Here is my code

```
//unlock
rbtnUTrue = new RadioButton("rbtnUnlock", "True");
rbtnUFalse = new RadioButton("rbtnUnlock", "False");

hp = new HorizontalPanel();
hp.add(rbtnUTrue);
hp.add(rbtnUFalse);
vlc.add(new FieldLabel(hp, "Has Unlock"), new VerticalLayoutData(1, -1, new Margins(10)));
if (rbtnUTrue.isChecked()) {
    dummy_u = 1;
} else if (rbtnUFalse.isChecked()) {
    dummy_u = 0;
}
```

but it always says that I clicked the false button

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Radio Button Value Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148034/get-radio-button-value-android)

Comment: i am sorry but i am not using eclipse. im using netbeans
but anyways, thank you

Comment: whatever you use the context will be the same

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey This question is about GWT, but suggested duplicate is about Android. It doesn't look like a valid dupe for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: "how to get data from radio buttons in gwt?":

`radioButton.getValue();` or `radioButton.isChecked();`

I'm not sure what do you want to achieve with the if-clause. If you need an initial value then just set it.

What you probably want to do is to register when the button is clicked:

```
rbtnUTrue.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Boolean> event) {
        if (rbtnUTrue.isChecked()) {
            dummy_u = 1;
        } else if (rbtnUFalse.isChecked()) {
            dummy_u = 0;
        }
    }
});
```